# modular symbols and the calculation of homology

Tags: number-theory, homology-cohomology, modular-forms

We have fundamental domain $F$ but we  have constructed a larger triangle $F+?$

Why do we need $F+?$

[image: enter image description here[![][1]]

[image]

Comment: I see no reference to $F^+$ in that picture.

Comment: It's in the 2nd picture. I will edit the question.

Comment: The goal is to find when $\sum_j \{\gamma_j\infty,\delta_j  \infty\} = 0$ to achieve this we need to define the relations generating the group. We don't "need" a larger triangle we are just encountering many triangles and edges identification.